# Ajax not calling php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using Ajax for the first time to call a php script. Unfortunately the script doesn't work. None of his instructions are executed. Here is the script where I use Ajax:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['errore'])) {
        switch ($_GET['errore']) {
            case 'authfailed':
                echo 
                '<script>
                $("#status").html("Credenziali Errate");
                $("#status").css("color","red"); 
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#status").html("Inserisci i dati forniti dall\'amministratore di sistema"); 
                    $("#status").css("color","black"); 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "../php/redirect.php",
                        data: {action: "redirect_area_personale"},
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function() {}
                    });
                }, 5000);
                </script>';
                break;                
        }
    }       
?>
```

And here is the script called:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'redirect_area_personale': 
            header("Location: ../pages/area_personale.php");
            die();
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Console doesn't display any error. It could be a silly mistake but that's my first try so any help is very appreciated!

Comment: First step (as often) is to have a look to dev tool, especially the Network tab. Do you see your request ? If so what is the status of the response ?

Comment: Check network tab, to see if the error is from ajax or php, if the network status is 200 then it is from php, if it is otherwise then is from the ajax or your first php script. Also try adding action: "action" to ajax script $.ajax({                   action :" action",
                        url: "../php/redirect.php",
                        data: {action: "redirect_area_personale"},
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function() {}
                    });
                }, 5000);  To go to network tabs click th3 3 dots on browser->more tools->....

Comment: @CedricCholley It doesn't show any error. I can even see that the script containg the ajax call and the script with the redirect are successfully called. They seem to be working, but no redirect to area_personale.php

Comment: @GeniusGeek No differences adding action:"action"

Comment: @CedricCholley I see that redirect.php is called by Ajax but status is 302 Found

Comment: @FabrizioCacciapuoti FYI i've just seen in [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) *Most contemporary clients accept relative URIs as argument to » Location:, but some older clients require an absolute URI including the scheme, hostname and absolute path.*
Just in case can you try an absolute URI in header method

Comment: okay, i understand what's going on now, ajax call to php expects a value not a redirect, so the error and thus not redirecting. Your redirect should be with ajax JavaScript on success function. So in area_personale.php echo out a value. Get this value in ajax and use window.location to redirect

Comment: @GeniusGeek Sorry for being late. You got it! You should write an answer so I can flag it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, i will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax needs a response from PHP and not a redirect. Your redirect should be done in the ajax success function using window.open or window.location.href like this.

```
 success: function(){
window.open("../path/area_personale.php", "_self");
}
```

or using window.location.href

```
  success: function(){
window.location.href="../path/area_personale.php";
}
```